# Why is the list of coordinates from the list not iterable and says that this is a box?

Tags: python

Faced a problem. I write down the coordinates of the found pictures in the list and click these pictures by the coordinates from the list, but I get an error.

`

```
getlist = []

if keyValue == False:
     while True:
         if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
            for i in range(0,21):
                # search coords
                if i != 0:
                    start = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(f'C:/Users/Marv/Desktop/PYTHON/new folder/{i}.png', confidence=0.9)
                    # coord to list
                    getlist.append(start)
                    print(f'{i} = {getlist[i-1]}')
            for c in getlist:
                if c == 0:
                    pyautogui.click(getlist[c])
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                else:
                    pyautogui.click(getlist[c])
                    time.sleep(0.7)
                    pyautogui.click(getlist[c])
                # print(getlist[c])
            keyValue = True
```

`

```
    pyautogui.click(getlist[c])
                    ~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Box
```

Comment: `c` is already an element of the list (not the index) because of the `for` loop.  Just replace `getlist[c]` with `c` in those click statements.

Comment: Are you trying to bypass a CAPTCHA here?  Why are you double-clicking some items?

Answer (score 0):

`c` is an ELEMENT of the list, not an INDEX, like in your first loop.  So:

```
            for c in getlist:
                pyautogui.click(c)
                time.sleep(0.5)
```